# Question about triangle formed by points lying on unit circle in Argand Plane following specific condition.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

If $\mathrm{A}\left({z}_1\right), \mathrm{B}\left({z}_2\right)$ and $\mathrm{C}\left({z}_3\right)$ be vertices of a $\triangle \mathrm{ABC}$ such that $\left|{z}_1\right|=\left|{z}_2\right|=\left|{z}_3\right|=1$ and there exist $\alpha \in\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that $z_1+z_2 \cos \alpha+z_3 \sin \alpha=0$, then what is the value of $\bar{z}_2 z_3+z_2 \bar{z}_3$?
My attempt
The magnitude of all the numbers is equal to $1$ so obviously they lie in on the unit circle but I don't really know how to interpret the second condition. I tried thinking that somehow I could take projections of $z_2$ and $z_3$ onto a line opposite to $z_1$ to make $-z_1$(like  vectors) but I didn't get anywhere with that.
PS:I encountered this problem in my institute's practice sheets for an undergraduate college entrance exam (JEE). So it would be preferable if the answers didn't use very advanced theorems that are not possible to understand at my level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to bring the mentioned second condition into play is to express all given complex numbers in the form, $z=\cos\left(\theta\right)+i\sin\left(\theta\right)$.

Therefore, we have,
$$z_1=\cos\left(\theta_1\right)+i\sin\left(\theta_1\right),\quad\space z_2=\cos\left(\theta_2\right)+i\sin\left(\theta_2\right), \quad\space\text{and}\quad\space z_3=\cos\left(\theta_3\right)+i\sin\left(\theta_3\right).$$

Now, we can express the second condition as shown below.
$$\cos\left(\theta_1\right)+\cos\left(\alpha\right)\cos\left(\theta_2\right) +\sin\left(\alpha\right)\cos\left(\theta_3\right)+i\left(\sin\left(\theta_1\right)+ \cos\left(\alpha\right)\sin\left(\theta_2\right)+ \sin\left(\alpha\right)\sin\left(\theta_3\right)\right)=0.$$

Therefore, we have,
$$\cos\left(\theta_1\right)=-\cos\left(\alpha\right)\cos\left(\theta_2\right)-\sin\left(\alpha\right)\cos\left(\theta_3\right)=0\qquad\text{and}\tag{1}$$
$$\sin\left(\theta_1\right)=- \cos\left(\alpha\right)\sin\left(\theta_2\right)- \sin\left(\alpha\right)\sin\left(\theta_3\right)=0.\qquad\quad\enspace\tag{2}$$

If we square (1) and (2), and then add those two together, we get,
$$\small{\cos^2\left(\theta_1\right)+\sin^2\left(\theta_1\right)= \cos^2\left(\alpha\right)+ \sin^2\left(\alpha\right)+2\cos\left(\alpha\right)\sin\left(\alpha\right)\left(\cos\left(\theta_2\right)\cos\left(\theta_3\right)+ \sin\left(\theta_2\right)\sin\left(\theta_3\right)\right)}.$$

Once simplified, this becomes,
$$1=1+\sin\left(2\alpha\right)\cos\left(\theta_2-\theta_3\right)$$

From this, we can deduce that,
$$\cos\left(\theta_2-\theta_3\right)=0.\tag{3}$$

Now, let us express $\bar{z}_2z_3$ and $z_2\bar{z}_3$.
$$\bar{z}_2z_3=\left(\cos\left(\theta_2\right)+i\sin\left(\theta_2\right)\right) \left(\cos\left(\theta_3\right)-i\sin\left(\theta_3\right)\right)\tag{4}$$
$$z_2\bar{z}_3=\left(\cos\left(\theta_2\right)-i\sin\left(\theta_2\right)\right) \left(\cos\left(\theta_3\right)+i\sin\left(\theta_3\right)\right)\tag{5}$$

Using (4) and (5), we shall write,
$$\bar{z}_2z_3+ z_2\bar{z}_3=2\left(\cos\left(\theta_2\right) \cos\left(\theta_3\right)+ \sin\left(\theta_2\right) \sin\left(\theta_3\right)\right)=2\cos\left(\theta_2-\theta_3\right)\tag{6}.$$
According to (3) and (6), $\bar{z}_2z_3+ z_2\bar{z}_3=0$.

Comment: This is correct according to the answer key and using this I have successfully solved the 2nd part of the question (max area ≈1.2). However this by itself only answers half of the question. I am unsure whether I should accept this is the answer. Perhaps some more experienced user could guide me on what to do here.

Comment: @Grimm I am happy to learn that you were able to solved the $2^{\text{nd}}$ part. On one hand, you did ask help only to clear the difficulty you had with the second condition.  On the other hand, the answerers of MSE always try to help and encourage askers to solve problem themselves. In fact, the code of conduct of MSE dissuades answerers from providing complete solutions. However, I am not going to ask you to accept my help. You can leave voting as it is. Thanks!

Comment: I have chosen to remove the 2nd part of the question and accept your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Grimm As I have mentioned in my previous comment, you could have kept the $2^\text{nd}$ part of your question intact while accepting the answer. In fact, that is the accepted practice in MSE. Thanks again.